# Different notions of equivalence of norms

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

I would like to understand deeper the notion of equivalence of norms, that can be understood in the sense that there are constants such that 
$$(1) \qquad aN_1 \leqslant N_2 \leqslant bN_1$$

or that there is an exponent such that
$$(2) \qquad N_1 = N_2^\alpha$$

What are the motivations for these choices depending on the interests? In particulier, is it clear that the Cauchy sequences are preserved if and only if the relation $(2)$ holds?

Comment: If $N_2$ is a norm then $N_2^{\alpha}$ is not a norm unless $\alpha =1$.

Comment: Two norms on a vector space are equivalent if and only if they induce the same topology if and only if the same sequences are Cauchy.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yet isn't the archimedean norm $|\cdot |^a $ also a norm for all $a \leqslant 1$? As well as any positive power of the $p$-adic norms for instance.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker My question is precisely about this: if we are interested in this notion of equivalent norm, that is to say those giving the same Cauchy sequences, then why does it imply (2)?

Comment: As Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out, (2) makes little sense in the current form. To explain the point, note that $\|\beta x\|^\alpha=|\beta|^\alpha \|x\|^\alpha$ needs to equal $|\beta| \|x\|^\alpha$ for $\|\cdot\|^\alpha$ to be a norm, and this will only hold, except for some degenerate cases, if $\alpha=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered by Michael Greinecker's comment.

I wrote this answer to make it visible *at first glance* that the question is no longer open.